# Probability of Child having Blood Type $AB$

Tags: probability

If a man has blood type $AB$, his wife has blood type $AA$, what is the probability that their child will be $AB$?
Is it $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with blood types, but if this is like any other alleles you receive one "letter" from the father and one from the mother chosen uniformly and independently at random.  The child gets bloodtype $AB$ then in this scenario if and only if the contribution from the father was the $B$ which in turn occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a Punnett square of the blood types:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{} & \text{A} & \text{B} \\\hline
 \text{A}  & \text{AA} & \text{AB}   \\\hline
 \text{A} & \text{AA}  & \text{AB} 
\end{array}
$$

where the top row represents the phenotype of the man (AB), and the leftmost column represents the phenotype of the woman (AA).

From the table, the probability that the offspring has blood type AB is $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

When the mother is homozygous for a particular locus (i.e. same allele), it simplifies the analysis to just consider her contributing a single allele all the time.

So mother contributes allele $A$ with probability $1$.

Father contributes allele $A$ with probability $\frac 12$ and allele $B$ with probability $\frac 12$.

Which means the offspring will have genotype $AB$ (blood group $AB$) with probability $\frac 12$ and genotype $AA$ (blood group $A$) with probability $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: the mother is $A_1A_2$, the father is $A_0B_0$  thus the child can be

- $A_1A_0$
- $A_1B_0$
- $A_2A_0$
- $A_2B_0$

Out of these $4$ possibilities how many are $AB$? What is the requested probability?